# Python 3.6: ambiguity in third root of decimal numbers

Tags: python-3.x, numbers, precision

The variable aa, type numpy.float(64) has the following value:

```
In: aa
Out: -0.11077542882130173
```

Taking the thrid-order root of this number creates ambiguity:

1. Directly typing yields the correct result

   ```
   In: -0.11077542882130173**(1/3)
   Out: -0.4802652307616457
   ```
2. Taking the third root of aa directly generates a warning and returns nan:

   ```
   In: aa**(1/3)
   __main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
   Out: nan
   ```
3. Converting to float generates a complex number:

   ```
   aa = float(aa)

   In: aa
   Out: -0.11077542882130173

   In: aa**(1/3)
   Out: (0.2401326153808229+0.41592189039398075j)
   ```

Anyone got an idea where this ambiguity stems from, and how I can get the first result without typing the number in?

Comment: You need brackets around your negative in #1. #2 works in Python 3.7. All generate a complex number (for me at least).

Comment: Here is an absolute last ditch solution ```eval(str(aa) + '**(1/3)')```

Comment: With brackets all do generate a complex number. Still the answer is wrong: e.g. `(-3)**3` yields `-27`, while `(-27)**(1/3)` yields:    `(1.5000000000000004+2.598076211353316j)`. Obviously it should be -3. Anyone knows why Py 3 produces this result?